# FullCalendar - With a Resource Day View,How to get resourceId when adding a new event

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to add a new event manually (selecting a time range) to a specific resource, so I need the resourceId after doing it to save the event on DB. I'm using the resource view of the calendar, working with multiple resources. When I try to select a time range (Select Method) to add a new event, I can get the startTime and endTime. But,the problem is, when I'm using the multi column view (resource view), I need the resourceId. Any solution?

i have tried this:

```
select: function(start, end, resourceId){alert(resourceId)}
```

the alert is: **false**

and this:

```
select: function(start, end, event){alert(event.resourceId)}
```

the alert is: **undefined**

Answer (score 1):

While adding events, make sure:

```
events: [
{
............
............
resourceId: 1 //
}
```

Then you can get resourceId by doing, `event.resourceId`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but it may help.

Assuming you have 'selectable' set to true in your fullcalendar options, try this:

```
select: function(start, end, allDay, event, resourceId) {
        alert(resourceId);
},
```

Hope this helps!